# Variable not recognized after if argument

Tags: android, if-statement

In the databse adapter, I'm trying to create a if (a & b) {select count from sqlite} .. full code as below.. however the cat variable is not recognized (as highlighted?

```
int samsung = 10;
int iphone = 20

public int getChick() {
    int cat = 0;
    if (red == 1 & blue == 2) {                             
        int pit = (int) DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT COUNT(*)  
            FROM table where one >= " + samsung + " and two >= " + iphone, null);   

        //////>>>>>> this cat is not recognized by eclipse    
        int cat = 0 + pit;
    }
    int dog = cat;
    return dog;
}
```

Thing is, I don't see how it is wrong. If you could please point it out to me. Thanks.

Comment: The code is badly formatted, so it's kind of difficult to read it, do you get a compile time error like `Duplicate variable` ?

Comment: yup. when mouseover it says 'duplicate local variable'. How do I fix this? Sorry, I'm very new to android and java

Comment: remove the `int` from `int cat = 0 + pit;` You have already declared it above and now you are declaring it again

Comment: Also it's almost certain you want your if check to be `if (red == 1 && blue == 2)`

Comment: Thanks codeMagic. It works after removing the int

Comment: @codeMagic exactly my point.

Comment: @blackbelt yeah, I didn't notice it at first. I was concentrated on `dog` for some reason. Maybe because I like them better :D

Comment: @codeMagic always two steps ahead

Comment: @blackbelt Haha...indeed!!

Comment: Thanks guys. I feel a little silly making such a silly oversight. If you'd post your answer I'd make it the answer, else, I'd right CP9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you declare `cat` in the first line of the method and again inside the if statement. you need to remove the `int` declaration on the second one

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int cat = 0 + pit;
```

to

```
cat = 0 + pit;
```

It looks like you're simply declaring it again when you've already declared it.